# php, how to sort arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have this example:

```
while (...){
echo "test:'.$a.',- group:'.$m.'
}
```

this will give me something like:

```
test:name2 - group:7
test:name3 - group:10
test:name4 - group:3
...
```

how do i display these results ordered by `group`, ex:

```
test:name2 - group:10
test:name3 - group:7
test:name4 - group:3
...
```

any ideas? i believe i can use something like `sort()` or `array_sort`, bu t i don't know  exactly

thanks.

edit: `$a`  and `m` are arrays with the values echoed out.

edit2:

i see that many people don't understand my question, well it is very simple to understand. Also i found my answer and here it is:

```
$HAy[]=array('a' => $a, 'm' => $m);
foreach($HAy as $c=>$key) {
$sort_num_rec[] = $key['a'];
}
array_multisort($sort_num_rec, SORT_DESC, $HAy);
foreach ($HAy as $ay){
//do something
}
```

was a bit confuse in the beginning, but i figure it out using `array_multisort`.

Comment: What is `$a` and what is `$m`?

Comment: You need to share your array structure, otherwise it's difficult to give you an advice ...

Comment: Give an example dataset of your initial array

Comment: What is `while(...)`? It might be helpful to know what `...` is and the array you are working with.

Comment: `$a` and `$m` are `name2` and `7`, `name3` and `10`, `name4` and `3`, etc

Comment: Post your code. I won't steal it. Well, maybe not at first.

Comment: this is a perfect google question...

Comment: Vote to close b/c OP seems to want a specific solution to an incomplete problem (post full code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sort multiple arrays based on one of the array's sorting order. use array_multisort();

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

```
array_multisort($m, $a);
```

this will sort both arrays according to the first arrays sort ordering.

Comment: thanks, i edited my post with the right answer for my case